# Finding the integral of exponential function?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

$\int{e^{-2x} \sqrt {e^{-2x+1}}dx}$

```
  I dont know what method or technique should i applied on this one i tried to $let u = \sqrt {e^{-2x+1}} $ but the derivate doesnt cancel the $e^{-2x}$ i even tried to let u the exponent still didnt get it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint:
$$
\int e^{-2x}\sqrt{e^{-2x+1}}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{e}\int e^{-2x}\sqrt{e^{-2x}}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{e}\int e^{-3x}\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: in -2x+1 what would happen in +1? since -2x is canceled out??

Comment: @Boruto is it clear now? $e^{-2x+1}=e(e^{-2x})$

Comment: oh i see many thanks!

Comment: @Boruto certainly